# What happens before _start function in /lib/ld-linux.so.2 is called?

Tags: linux, ld, init

I found that the entry point of programs is the dynamic linker, /lib/ld-linux-so.2 in my machine.

[image]

```
readelf -h /lib/ld-linux.so.2 |grep Entry 
Entry point address:               0x11d0
```

Actually the entry point is 0xb7fdf1d0. Some context information is as follows.

```
gdb-peda$ context_code
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]
   0xb7fdf1c3:  ret    
   0xb7fdf1c4:  lea    esi,[esi+0x0]
   0xb7fdf1ca:  lea    edi,[edi+0x0]
=> 0xb7fdf1d0 <_start>: mov    eax,esp
   0xb7fdf1d2 <_start+2>:   call   0xb7fe2c80 <_dl_start>
   0xb7fdf1d7 <_dl_start_user>: mov    edi,eax
   0xb7fdf1d9 <_dl_start_user+2>:   call   0xb7fdf1c0
   0xb7fdf1de <_dl_start_user+7>:   add    ebx,0x1fe16
gdb-peda$ bt
#0  0xb7fdf1d0 in _start () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
gdb-peda$ i r esp
esp            0xbffff3e0   0xbffff3e0
```

[image]

But the stack is already inited at this time, and it saved the enviroment variables and args of program.So who inited the stack before _start function?

Answer (score 1):

The kernel sets up the stack.

When the kernel handles the exec of the dynamic loader, it initializes some data structures that keep track of the virtual memory map and stack location. In [fs/exec.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/fs/exec.c#n652) the stack location is setup.

When the scheduler hands control to this new process, it will set the value of the stack pointer to the corresponding value.

Comment: You are right, the bash program will transfer control to the kernel by "execve()" function.